# Merge [amazon-sts] into [aws-sts]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I just noticed that Stack Overflow has [amazon-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sts) and [aws-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sts) tags with 22 and 8 posts respectively at the time of this posting.

As these two tags mean absolutely the same (AWS Security Token Service), can [amazon-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sts) be merged into [aws-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sts) (or making as a synonym)?

Comment: Which one is the current name of the service? If it is AWS Security Token Service then the aws-sts tag should be the synonyme target

Comment: current name is 'AWS Security Token Service'. @BDL, I agree with you. should I rename the title of this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done:

[aws-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sts) ← [amazon-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sts).

As established in the comments, the official name is AWS Security Token Service, so I've made [aws-sts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sts) the "master" tag. I also manually merged the tag wiki excerpts. The tag wiki could use some additional love from a knowledgeable benefactor.